# CSP behavior while sending Different CSP header value in different calls

Tags: google-chrome, content-security-policy

I want to understand how the CSP will be applied when different REST responses in the page have different header value for CSP. We dont have any meta tag for CSP. CSP is applied only through response headers.

Lets take the scenarios of 3 APIs

1. `GET /api/v1/users` - `Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' google.com; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' google.com`
2. `GET /api/v1/roles` - `Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'; img-src 'self'`
3. `GET /api/v1/permission` - `Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' google.com; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' google.com`

In this case, what will be the CSP considered by the browser for subsequent requests?

Also, in my understanding, server sets the CSP in the response header to inform browser about what  content will be allowed going forward. is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

A CSP determines what resources can be loaded on a page and is only applied on pages that are rendered in the browser, typically with content type "text/html". So there is no benefit in setting it on images, scripts, styles etc.

The CSP that makes sense for an API is frame-ancestors 'none', see https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/REST_Security_Cheat_Sheet.html#security-headers for an explanation.